# Aurelia Router/Child Router - 'Error: Route not found'

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm trying to set up an app with the following configuration:

~ There are two base pages controlled by authorization

- Login Page - If no session-id
- Dashboard Page - If logged in

~ Once on the Dashboard page I want to use this as a sort of container for other views. The dashboard is basically just a template with a navigation bar and `router-view`. I want the router view to be able switch between 2 pages/views while keeping the dashboard/navigation in place as the layout. The two pages are to switch between

- Update-Feed
- Test-Page

Here are the files as I currently have them set up

**app.ts**

```
import {NavigationInstruction, Next, Redirect, Router, RouterConfiguration} from 'aurelia-router';

/**
 * Main application router, controls views by authorization
 */
export class App {

  public router: any;

  public configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router): void {
    config.title = 'Dashboard';
    config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep);

    // These are the two main routes a login page and a dashboard. 
    // Which page is visible is controlled by the authorization step
    config.map([
      {route: ['', 'pmdash'], name: 'pmdash', moduleId: './pages/pmdash/pmdash', nav: true,  auth: true},
      {route: 'login',        name: 'login',  moduleId: './pages/login/login',   nav: false, auth: false, title: 'Login'}
    ]);
    this.router = router;
    console.log(this.router);
  }
}

export class AuthorizeStep {

  // Method may be used elsewhere to verify user is logged in
  public static isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    let sessionID = sessionStorage.getItem('sessionID');
    return (typeof sessionID !== 'undefined' && sessionID !== null);
  }

  public run(navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction, next: Next): Promise<any> {

    if (navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions().some(i => i.config.auth)) {
      let isLoggedIn = AuthorizeStep.isLoggedIn();

      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        return next.cancel(new Redirect('login'));
      }
    }
    return next();
  }
}
```

`app.ts` controls whether you land on a login page or the dashboard based on a session-id. This works, however once landing on the dashboard page it starts getting messed up... Here's the dashboard and corresponding navbar files

**pmdash.html**

```
<!-- Base template for PM Dashboard views -->

<template>

  <require from="../../components/navbar/navbar"></require>
  <nav-bar></nav-bar>
  <router-view></router-view>

</template>
```

**pmdash.ts**

```
import {Router, RouterConfiguration} from 'aurelia-router';

/**
 * Child router for Dashboard pages/views
 */
export class DashBoard {

  public router: Router;

  // On immediate navigation to the dashboard this loads `update-feed`, which works
  // However it only works because it is assigned the base route ''.
  // If I try to navigate to `update-feed` or `test-page` by url I get `Error: Route not found:` in console 
  public configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    config.map([
      {route: ['', 'update-feed'], name: 'update-feed', moduleId: './pages/update-feed/update-feed', nav: true, title: 'Feed'},
      {route: ['test-page'],       name: 'test-page',   moduleId: './pages/test-page/test-page',     nav: true, title: 'Test'}
    ]);
    this.router = router;

    // These console logs show the router is the child of `AppRouter` and has all the routes assigned to it, like it should.
    console.log(this.router);
    console.log(this.router.routes);
  }

}
```

**navbar.html**

```
<template>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

    <!-- Here is an effort to bind the router to the navigation -->
    <div class="navbar-header" router.bind="router">

      <!-- Here again clicking on the link gives `Route not found: /update-feed`-->
      <a class="navbar-brand" route-href="route: update-feed">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <span>PM Dashboard</span>
      </a>

      <!-- This works. It calls the logout function which then redirects to the login page on the main router-->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-right" click.delegate="logOut()">Log Out</button>
    </div>
  </nav>

</template>
```

**navbar.ts**
Right now `navbar.ts` only contains the `logOut()` function so I'm skipping the code for brevity.

Now here are the two pages that I want the `pmdash.ts` child router to control. Basically the way I have it set up I would expect that when landing on the `pmdash` page/route then the `pmdash` view/viewmodel should handle these pages/views while staying in `pmdash` as sort of a template with the navbar on top, then depending on links (or default) switching out which view is displayed below the navbar.

**update-feed.html**

```
<template>

  <h1>You currently have no projects needing updated.</h1>

  <!-- Clicking this link gives `Error: Route not found: /test-page` in console-->
  <a route-href="route: test-page">click for test page</a>

</template>
```

**test-page.html**

```
<template>
  TESTING
  <!-- Clicking this link gives `Error: Route not found: /update-feed` -->
  <a route-href="route: update-feed">click for route page</a>
</template>
```

`update-feed.html` and `test-page.html` both have associated `.ts` files as well but for now they are blank.

I just do not understand what I am doing wrong. Am I misunderstanding how the router/child-routers handle pages on a fundamental level? Is there any way to make the configuration work like I currently have it, or do I need to scrap this approach and try something completely different?

Again, the main issue is that `pmdash` child-router will not switch views with the `update-feed` and `test-page` routes. However, if I assign either of the routes as `route: ''` then it will load fine, but I still can never link to the other route/view.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, please add and accept and answer - rather than edit your original post.

Comment: I left it open since this "answer" is more of a workaround/hack. I will edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I've "fixed" this, here's how:

At first I didn't really think that [this SO question][1] was relevant to my situation, but it was.

Basically the issue is with handling absolute routes and the base route (ie `route: ''`) not being handled correctly when passing off routing to a child router.

The workaround is to make the parent router redirect like so (using my own `app.ts` from above as example):

```
  public configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router): void {
    config.title = 'Dashboard';
    config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep);
    config.map([
      {route: '',      redirect: 'dashboard'},
      {route: 'dashboard', name: 'pmdash', moduleId: './pages/pmdash/pmdash', nav: true,  auth: true},
      {route: 'login',     name: 'login',  moduleId: './pages/login/login',   nav: false, auth: false, title: 'Login'}
    ]);
    this.router = router;
    console.log(this.router);
  }
```

This is apparently [a workaround to a known issue with how the router handles an array of routes with a child router](https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/27). However, although the workaround does work, console is now spitting this warning, `Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Object]
    at _buildNavigationPlan....` whenever the app root route is hit. This warning does not seem to have manifested itself into any actual issues yet...

what a headache

Comment: I can answer the "warning a promise was rejected thing for you ....." :-)

Comment: @shawty: by all means! You have a solution?

Comment: Basically, you get that when you reject without using a "throw", I had it a bunch in the past few days on the project Iv'e been working on.  It's not Aurelia that's doing it, it's actually Bluebird the promise library AU uses.  In your catch, if you "throw new Error('foo')" you'll find you don't get the warning, but if you "throw Error({prop: 1, prop2: 'two'})" you will.  There is however a secret :-)  If you "throw Error({name: "myCustomErrorName", message: "My custom error message", ... then your custom data here ... })" , blue bird thinks it's a legit new Error as the sigs match.

Comment: Interesting. Yea I gathered it was a bluebird thing but just kinda gave up further inspection. Was burnt out just from getting this together haha. I'll give it a try and post back. Thanks!

Comment: This allows you to throw the error back, pass custom data, but not get the warning.  If it's coming from above your call EG: in au-fetch, then you need to wrap it in your own promise, and re-throw it in the catch.

Comment: Okay, just looked at it again and i'm not sure where this `catch` is you're talking about... would it be in this router snippet or somewhere else? I'm using `fetch` elsewhere for the user api but after testing that it doesn't seem related. Any chance you could hit me with a code snippet?

Comment: I'll go one better... gimme 10 mins and I'll upload my AU skeleton project that includes this to my github account gh.com/shawty

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'm afk now but I'll check it out when I get back

Comment: Took me a little longer than planned, but here you go: https://github.com/shawty/aurelia-app-template I actually didn't use the catch I was on about above, but anyway it's a full authenticated solution, so might actually just solve the entire question for you.

Comment: Right on, I was just looking it over :)

Comment: as long as it helps, i'm happy :-)

Comment: I would still like to know where exactly that catch goes. I found some references to the `useStandardConfiguration` router property as being the source but with no solutions like you suggested. Is that where you applied this fix? If you wouldn't mind I could post this as a new question tomorrow and you could show the answer. That would be great since there isn't really a solid answer for this that I've found and it's obviously something people keep running into.

Comment: look in my httpservice file, see the try catch that's inside each http fetch call? You would usually catch there, then re-throw.  Look also at the http interceptor function in main.ts, same thing again you would throw not new Error there, but keep same sig, i just ended up eventing most of it because it worked for my use case, if instead you throw using the method I mentioned, you get to trap things properly in catch at your app level EG: this.http.get(blah).then(...).catch(...) and still pas custom data over.